# Adicionar opção em um select na ordem original

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Olá, eu possuo uma função que permite remover e readicionar opções de um `<select>`, o "problema" é que na hora de readicionar a opção ele vai lá pro final do select ao invés de se manter na ordem original, eu pensei em utilizar uma array adicionando os valores já na ordem que eu preciso e de alguma forma verficiar a posição do *Stack 01* nessa array, alguém poderia me dizer se essa forma que eu disse seria válida ou tem alguma outra maneira mais simples de fazer isso, e como poderia por em prática.

Atualmente estou usando esse método para adicionar, lembrando que esse select é criado pelo próprio jquery, então algumas formas não funcionam:

```
$('select').append(`<option>Stack 01</option>`)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a função [prepend](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/):

> O método .prepend() insere o conteúdo especificado como o primeiro filho de cada elemento na coleção jQuery.

```
$('select').prepend(`<option>Stack 01</option>`)
```

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/313973)

Comment: @KayoBruno editei (-: